# Matplotlib.pyplot Legend is populating points for every data point

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphing

I am plotting two separate y-values on a graph (same scale), and want a legend to indicate that one is charge, and the other is discharge.

the x and y data (cycle,charge_specific_capacity, discharge_specific_capacity) are from arrays.

```
  fig = plt.figure()
  ax = plt.subplot(111)
  ax.plot(cycle,charge_specific_capacity,'go',label='Charge')
  ax.plot(cycle,discharge_specific_capacity,'ro',label='Discharge')
  plt.title('Specific Capacity vs Cycle')
  plt.ylabel ('Specific Capacity (mAh/g)')
  plt.xlabel('Cycle Number')
  plt.legend(loc='upper right',shadow=True, fancybox=True, numpoints=1)
  plt.savefig(graph_path_speccap)
  plt.show()
```

Produces this:
[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlX6Y.png)

My question is, how can I have the legend only showing 1 green circle for charge, and 1 red circle for discharge?

Comment: the problem comes from the shape of your data. flatten them first

Comment: @bobrobbob - This worked. Thank you!